# Email delivery (spam?) - Email not received with some ISP emails

Tags: codeigniter, email, spam

I'm having a problem with some emails not being delivered with some ISP email address
Common email example reported by users :  "xx@free.fr", "@bellsouth.net"

I don't really have a way to "test" why they don't get the emails. I told them to verify spam folder and they aren't there.. I have test account for popular email service "gmail, hotmail" and they work fine.

The emails I'm sending are common emails from my domain website (registration, confirm account, forgot password).  I don't send any bulk email. I'm using goDaddy as hosting service.

I have set up SPF on my domain, and the email are sent with PHP(codeIgniter) - See bottom for how the mail is sent with code

Here is an example of mail that I sent that is blocked by theses ISP:

```
Delivered-To: tdfdestgmfdsailmaxmt123okdddf3@gmail.com
Received: by 10.112.159.166 with SMTP id xd6csp1482168lbb;
        Wed, 17 Dec 2014 10:27:57 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.50.61.238 with SMTP id t14mr9680303igr.34.1418840877015;
        Wed, 17 Dec 2014 10:27:57 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <admin@maximumtrainer.com>
Received: from p3nlsmtpcp01-03.prod.phx3.secureserver.net (p3nlsmtpcp01-03.prod.phx3.secureserver.net. [184.168.200.142])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id hh16si4059486icb.62.2014.12.17.10.27.56
        for <tdfdestgmfdsailmaxmt123okdddf3@gmail.com>;
        Wed, 17 Dec 2014 10:27:56 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of admin@maximumtrainer.com designates 184.168.200.142 as permitted sender) client-ip=184.168.200.142;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of admin@maximumtrainer.com designates 184.168.200.142 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=admin@maximumtrainer.com
Received: from p3plcpnl0063.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ([184.168.200.112])
    by p3nlsmtpcp01-03.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with : CPANEL :
    id UiR51p01s2S0Aj401iR5yP; Wed, 17 Dec 2014 11:25:05 -0700
Received: from p3plcpnl0063.prod.phx3.secureserver.net ([184.168.200.112]:34603 helo=maximumtrainer.com)
    by p3plcpnl0063.prod.phx3.secureserver.net with esmtpa (Exim 4.84)
    (envelope-from <admin@maximumtrainer.com>)
    id 1Y1JKF-0001bp-W0
    for tdfdestgmfdsailmaxmt123okdddf3@gmail.com; Wed, 17 Dec 2014 11:27:56 -0700
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Wed, 17 Dec 2014 18:27:55 +0000
From: "Maximum Trainer" <admin@maximumtrainer.com>
To: tdfdestgmfdsailmaxmt123okdddf3@gmail.com
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?Bienvenue?=
Reply-To: "admin@maximumtrainer.com" <admin@maximumtrainer.com>
X-Sender: admin@maximumtrainer.com
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <5491cb2be1fa8@maximumtrainer.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-AntiAbuse: This header was added to track abuse, please include it with any abuse report
X-AntiAbuse: Primary Hostname - p3plcpnl0063.prod.phx3.secureserver.net
X-AntiAbuse: Original Domain - gmail.com
X-AntiAbuse: Originator/Caller UID/GID - [47 12] / [47 12]
X-AntiAbuse: Sender Address Domain - maximumtrainer.com
X-Get-Message-Sender-Via: p3plcpnl0063.prod.phx3.secureserver.net: authenticated_id: admin@maximumtrainer.com
X-Source: 
X-Source-Args: 
X-Source-Dir:
```

CodeIgniter sender function:

```
function send_confirmation_mail($email, $first_name, $confirm_code) {

    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('email'); // load library

    $CI->email->from ( 'admin@maximumtrainer.com', 'Maximum Trainer' );
    $CI->email->to ( $email );
    $CI->email->subject ( lang('email_activate_title') );   

    $link =  base_url(). index_page(). lang('url_confirm_user').  "/". $confirm_code;

    $message = lang('email_hello'). $first_name. ", \r\n". 
            lang('email_activate_thank_you'). "\r\n\r\n".
            lang('email_activate_click_link'). "\r\n".
            $link. "\r\n\r\n".
            lang('email_activate_farewwell'). "\r\n".
            lang('email_linkMT');

    $CI->email->message( $message );

    if ( ! $CI->email->send()) {
        $CI->messages->add("error send_confirmation_mail", "error");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Server config :

```
$config['useragent']        = 'CodeIgniter';        
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';        
#$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'p3plcpnl0063.prod.phx3.secureserver.net';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'yyyyyy@maximumtrainer.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['smtp_port']        = 25;  #465 to test doesnt seem to work
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;
$config['wordwrap']         = FALSE;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'text';
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['validate']         = FALSE;
$config['priority']         = 3;
$config['crlf']             = "\r\n";
$config['newline']          = "\r\n";
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = FALSE;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
```

Are there any services to diagnose what could be the cause of the problem? I can't register for free with these email providers in order to test.

Comment: In python you have the validate_email module that can check for format, valid SMTP server, and even verify email address exists: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/validate_email

Comment: check your mail server's logs, see what happens when your server tries to deliver to these hosts.  if they accept it, then there's NOTHING you can do without seeing what the email looks like on the other end (e.g. spam score headers).

Comment: Clearly your code works because it's delivering mail. Debugging external spam filters is off-topic (because it's not your code and it's almost impossible)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, it's just frustrating to debug and i'm loosing customer that can't confirm account.  Maybe I could see a SPAM score utility to debug my mails, so I have the best chance to be received?